# L'expression néerlandaise « mettre des mots dans la bouche »

Tags: expressions, anglais, néerlandais

En néerlandais on dit parfois que quelqu’un « met des mots dans la bouche d’autrui ». 
Cette façon de s’exprimer s’applique lorsque l’on prétend mensongèrement qu’un locuteur a tenu un propos. Ni les dictionnaires qui je possède ni les ressources en ligne ne connaissent de traduction. Je tente donc de décrire les finesses de cette tournure, pour que vous puissiez la traduire.

Tout d’abord, c’est une tournure que l’on entend régulièrement quand plusieurs hommes politiques discutent. On l’entend moins souvent hors ce cadre, lors d'une querelle par exemple.

Il s’agit souvent d’un propos d’où ressort la malveillance du locuteur, un énoncé qui va à l’encontre de l’avis de la plupart des gens qui entendent la délibération. Son interlocuteur essaie d’éveiller la hargne des auditeurs envers son émule, en exagérant ce qu’il avait dit, de façon à ébranler ceux qui écoutent. Il tente d’amadouer ceux qui écoutent sa parole comme ça. Il dit toutes ces choses d'un ton convaincu. Il utilise habilement les faiblesses dans les paroles de son interlocuteur pour lui reprocher des choses. Un quiproquo lui sert à acculer son adversaire.

Le reproché rétorque souvent : « Je n’ai jamais dit ça », « vous me mettez des mots dans la bouche », « parlez pour vous ». (Je n’ai pas tout confiance que la dernière tournure traduise bien la pensée visée, votre conseil est bienvenu.)

À moindre mesure, on peut utiliser cette expression même si personne n’essaie de noircir quelqu’un. Alors on la prononce pour avertir qu’on a mal estimé l’avis de quelqu’un qui parle.

Pouvez-vous m’aider à trouver une traduction pour ce dicton ?

Comment: J’ai consenti aux changements suggérés, merci! Il y encore une chose que je veux savoir. Pourquois avez-vous remplacé le mot « outrant » par « rendant outrageux » ?

Comment: « Outrant » est le participe présent du verbe « outrer », donc son emploi était grammaticalement correct. Mais pas le sens de la phrase : avec « en outrant ce qu’il avait dit » (de mémoire), j'aurais tendance à comprendre que « ce qui est dit » devient « outré » (« choqué » / « révolté », plutôt qu'« outrageant » ou « choquant »), ce qui ne me semblait pas correct. Qui plus est, le mot « outrant » est très peu utilisé, je ne me rappelle pas l'avoir déjà vu employé.

Comment: @Qeole: le sens voulu était surement « exagérer », et l'emploi de « outrer » était correct, mais c'est un sens pour lequel on fait rarement appel à ce verbe de nos jours.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Très bien, au temps pour moi. Je ne connaissais pas cet emploi du verbe.

Comment: A noter que l'on ne devrait pas parler de la traduction d'un dicton ici, mais de celle d'une expression. Un dicton est une phrase populaire qui est devenu un proverbe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Traduction

Je ne vois pas de dicton équivalent en français. L'expression qui me vient le plus aisément en tête serait de « *prêter des propos* » à quelqu'un (ici, *prêter* a le sens d'*attribuer*). Exemple de réaction en débat :

> Vous me prêtez des propos que je n'ai jamais tenu.

Ou bien :

> Vous m'attribuez à tort ces paroles.

Lorsque les mots que l'on « met dans la bouche » de l'adversaire, selon ton dicton, sont basés sur un discours antérieur, mais différent, l'interlocuteur se défendra souvent en déclarant :

> Vous déformez mes propos / mon discours / ce que j'ai dit.

## *Parlez pour vous !*

« Parlez pour vous ! » signifie « je ne partage pas votre avis », « je ne suis pas d'accord avec ce que vous dites » ; sous-entendu : « ce que vous dites vous concerne peut-être, mais ce n'est pas mon cas ».

Cette tournure pourrait en effet être employée pour se défendre dans un tel contexte, mais elle ne me semble pas la plus adaptée. Elle ne rend pas la notion que l'un des interlocuteurs attribue à son adversaire un discours qu'il n'a pas tenu.

## Des mots dans la bouche

Pour l'anecdote, il existe une expression en français qui parle, non pas de *mettre*, mais d'*enlever*, ou plus exactement d'*ôter* les mots de la bouche de quelqu'un. Elle est employée lorsqu'une personne marque son accord avec une autre, et fait savoir qu'elle s'apprêtait à tenir les mêmes propos :

> Tu m'ôtes les mots de la bouche !

Autrement dit : « j'allais justement dire la même chose que toi. »

Comment: Merci, vôtre réponse rend des choses  plus claires. 
D’ailleurs, je pense que j’ai vu deux épellations fausses.
Est-ce que « tord » devrait être « tort », et « différend » devrait être « différent » ?
Le dernier dicton est aussi un dicton néerlandais d’ailleurs, avec le même sens

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin Tout à fait. Stéphane est déjà passé par là pour la correction de « différent », je vais immédiatement redresser cet autre « tort » fait à l'orthographe. Et prendre note de me relire la prochaine fois…

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin Attention: « Est-ce votre sac ? » : pas d'accent sur *votre* (adjectif possessif). « Non, c'est le vôtre » : accent.

Answer (score 3):

En complément de ce qui a déjà été dit et proposé très justement par Qeole et Xavier, je propose de considérer l'expression « ***Faire dire à quelqu'un** ce qu'il n'a pas dit* » comme dans les exemples suivants :

> Vous me faites dire quelque chose que je n'ai jamais dit !
>
> Il lui fait dire ce qu'il n'a pas dit.

Cette structure est aussi celle qui est donnée dans le [*Dictionnaire des expressions et tournures calquées sur l'anglais* de Michel Parmentier](https://books.google.be/books?id=o5DR-z0jNucC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=mettre%20des%20mots%20dans%20la%20bouche&source=bl&ots=7LdTZmOBvE&sig=qtb-1uZh3yv4jzqpk3ytMhLN_iI&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCkemm8fXOAhVkApoKHXT0DHoQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q&f=false) (PUL, 2006) :

[image: Extrait du Dictionnaire: mettre des mots dans la bouche de quelqu'un]

On peut aussi penser à l'expression voisine « *Faire dire (à quelqu'un/quelque chose) ce que l'on veut* », pour prêter une interprétation supposément erronée à un message par exemple.

> On peut faire dire ce que l'on veut aux statistiques.

Answer (score 2):

Peut-être quelque chose du genre:

> Vous déformez mes propos

Ou bien si c'est vraiment complètement inventé, on peut répondre:

> Vous affabulez mon cher!

Affabuler consiste à dire une affabulation. Selon le dictionnaire, une affabulation est **une manière purement imaginaire de raconter des faits**. Affabuler revient donc à conter une fable, et est donc quelque chose d'irréel, de purement imaginaire.

Dans un débat politique on pourrait aussi employer une expression ayant un sens qui peut-être adapté à votre situation:

> Interlocuteur 1: Vous avez dit que vous alliez baisser fortement les impôts!
>
> Interlocuteur 2: Je n'ai jamais dit cela. Vous prenez vos désirs pour des réalités!

Answer (score 1):

Une autre façon de l'exprimer  est "**parler à la place de**".

> Ne parlez pas à ma place !

Cependant, dire :

> Il parle à la place de XXX

ne me semble pas naturel, et est ambigu. Si l'on se permet de sortir du sens littéral, on pourrait dire aussi :

> XXX joue au  ventriloque, et fait dire...

ou en réponse ironique :

> Je ne vous savais pas ventriloque : ce que j'ai vraiment dit...